# Server losing %EC2_HOME%\bin path

Tags: amazon-web-services, path, amazon-ec2, environment-variables

I downloaded the AWS CLI tools to a server, setup the Java and EC2 path in the environment variables, and set the %EC2_HOME%\bin in Path.  I'm running a batch file using Windows Task Scheduler that creates snapshots of 4 of my volumes.  The snapshots do get created at the specified time, but then the computer loses the \b path.  I run ec2-describe-regions in the command prompt, but get the "not a recognized command.." error.  When I got to the Path environment variable and just save it, I can run any api call. The ec2\bin path is still in there.

Is there an issue with Windows Task Scheduler interfering with Path associations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebooting Windows. According to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/331077/accessing-environment-variables-in-a-scheduled-task), it solved a similar issue:

> It turns out you can use them quite easily (environment variables), it just requires a machine
>   reboot to pick up changes in particular circumstances.

Comment: Which is, of course, the first thing I should have done after setting this all up.  Thanks!!

Comment: I'll have to reboot the server tonight after all the users are gone.  But if it works, definitely.

Comment: Yeah, that reboot did the trick.  5 days now of automatic snapshots working.